# How do I make this AppleScript accept both files and folders?

Tags: applescript

How do I make this AppleScript also accept folders? Right now it only accepts files.

```
set X to choose file with prompt "Please select some files or folders:" with multiple selections allowed
```

Comment: You can't, it's either **choose file** _v_ : Choose a file on a disk or server, or **choose folder** _v_ : Choose a folder on a disk or server

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in vanilla AppleScript. You'd either have to incorporate AppleScriptObjC and create a custom open dialog using NSOpenPanel, or shift to Automator and use the "Ask For Finder Items" action.